# How to refactor this when some of my models are empty or null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently my FullName is 'undefined undefined' at the end of the string when vm.LocationId or vm.ZoneId are undefined or null or no match is found.

What is the better or safer way to generate the FullName value if either vm.LocationId or vm.ZoneId are null.

```
 vm.Company.FullName =
                ($(vm.CompanyList).filter(function(i, n) {
                    return n.ModelId == vm.CompanyId;
                })).prop("Name") + " " +

                $filter("filter")(vm.CopmanyYears, vm.YearID) +" "+

                ($(vm.LocationList).filter(function (i, n) {
                    return n.LocationId == vm.LocationId;
                })).prop("Name") + " " +

                ($(vm.ZoneList).filter(function (i, n) {
                    return n.ZoneId == vm.ZoneId;
                })).prop("Name") ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all split your code into several lines then make assignment.

```
const company = $(vm.CompanyList).filter(company => company.ModelId === vm.CompanyId) || {}
const year = $filter(`filter`)(vm.CopmanyYears, vm.YearID)
const location = $(vm.LocationList).filter(
  location => location.LocationId === vm.LocationId
) || {}
const zone = $(vm.ZoneList).filter(zone => zone.ZoneId === vm.ZoneId) || {}

const names = [company.name, year, location.name, zone.name]
vm.Company.FullName = names.filter(v => v).join(` `)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your `filter` method. If `$(vm.CompanyList).filter` returns array you should use `find` instead `filter` method:
`$(vm.CompanyList).find(company => company.ModelId === vm.CompanyId)`

Comment: What is it `$filter("filter")(vm.CopmanyYears, vm.YearID)`? Is it correct?